# Wordpress: for 100 pages site, use 100 page templates or 1 with include functions?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm now using Different page templates for all pages which I create in my Wordpress. I'm using WordPress for Intranet Portal for a company. 
For all pages, which I build, I need different php code.

What is the correct way for 100 pages site? Create for all pages their own page template, and put it to themes/.../page-templates or create one page with:

```
<?php 
switch($current_page_name) {
   case "about-us";
include(site_url('/pages/about-us.php'));
   break;
   case "contact-form";
include(site_url('/pages/contact-form.php'));
   break;
}
?>
```

But how can I get $current_page_name variable? for example I have page:
http://192.168.210.140/sales-funnel/todolist/
As i think, there need to be:

```
case "sales-funnel/todolist/";
```

Is it correct, to create **themes\twentyten\page-templates\one-column.php**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Main template one-column
 */
 add_action('template_redirect','my_redirect');

        function my_redirect(){
            get_header();
            echo '
            <div id="container" class="one-column">
            <div id="content" role="main">  
            ';
            global $wp; //global $wp object it will return us request
            global $wpdb;
            echo $wp->request;
            switch($wp->request) {

                 case "sales-funnel/todolist":
                 status_header( 200 );  
                 include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/sf/todolist.php');
                 break;
                 case "sales-funnel/add-deal":
                 status_header( 200 );  
                 include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/pages/sf/add-deal.php');
                 break;
            }
            echo '
            </div><!-- #content -->
            </div><!-- #container -->
            ';
            get_footer();
                exit;
        }
        my_redirect()
?>
```

And use it for example for 50 pages, simply add a case statement to this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook:

```
 add_action('template_redirect','my_redirect');

        function my_redirect(){
            global $wp; //global $wp object it will return us request

            switch($wp->request) {

                 case "sales-funnel/todolist":
                 status_header( 200 );  
                 include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/my-page-template.php');
                 break;
                 // Todo add more cases here
            }
                exit;
        }
```

If you want to change the title of each page then you can use [wp_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) filter as well.

Comment: So, I need to create one template with this code, and use it for all my pages? and if I create a new page, then I simply add new `case "new-page": status_header( 200 ); include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/my-new-page.php'); break;` And for 100 pages syte there will be 100 switch cases?

Comment: but which template I need to choose when I create page in Wordpress? I think, you don't understand me correctly. I need for example 3 templates, 1.Page with sidebar, 2.Page without sidebar, 3.page without menu. And If i create new page in wordpress, I will choose one from that, and also add to this template case row

Comment: if you want to add your custom template in dropdown then you should read https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Answer (score 1):

First thing if you really have 100 different templates for a single website you should think about it. Do you really need that much templates? Usually a Wordpress website shouldn't have more than ten templates in most cases. Maybe there is something wrong that had be done on the webdesign, or chosing Wordpress was not the best idea for your project.

Any way, the right way to proceed is as you described: create a template file with a comment on the top naming the template, and select it in the template dropdown when you're editing a page. Try to have only few of them, as you said "page with sidebar", "page without sidebar" etc. should be enough.

Then, use the content of the page to build your whole page. You could do some [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in order to display specific blocks, or maybe [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to send some booleans to the template (display this thing or not in the sidebar, etc). With a plugin like [Custom Field Suite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/) or [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) you can easily create groups of fields for a specific template. Finally, for widgets, you can use [Widgets Context](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/) in order to hide/show widgets on specific sections.

Comment: So, it means, that I can do that, what I described in `Is it correct, to create themes\twentyten\page-templates\one-column.php: <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Main template one-column
 */
 add_action('template_redirect','my_redirect');` ?

Comment: Yes that's how you're supposed to work. Though as I said don't multiply your template files for each particular case. Try to isolate the main templates, and work with custom fields / shortcodes / widgets in order to handle specific cases.